# Is it possible to automatically bring data with a lookup into another column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, lookup-column

I have a SharePoint site that I am working on and it has 2 lists that I am working with. One list is a list of vendors that my company uses and has details about the vendors. The other is a list of bills/expenses.

I have a lookup in place that allows you to add the vendor to a column on the bill file and I want it to automatically put what budget category that vendor is (this information is already linked in the vendor doc) into the bill file as well.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to bring columns from vendor list to bills list with lookup column? What is the data/column type of those columns? You can extend lookup column to bring additional columns from lookup column settings. However it does not support all column types. Check this link to check supported types: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I needed, just had to change the data type on the vendor sheet. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to bring additional columns from vendor list to bills list with lookup column.

You can extend lookup column to bring additional columns from lookup column settings.

However SharePoint does not support extending all column types with lookup column. Hence you have to use the supported column types only.

Check this Microsoft documentation for supported column types in lookup: [Create list relationships by using lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)